# Bootstrap theme not displaying correctly at all

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I am building a site based off of Bootstrap Carousel theme... unfortunately nothing is working when I copy the index and css file into my directory. Are there other files aside from the CSS that need to be in the same directory? like the glyphicons and all the buttons. It's literally just displaying the html... no carousel or anything.

Comment: Are you sure the page has loaded the CSS?

Answer (score 1):

nothing needs to be in same directory! just check you have the right path to the files! and all are loaded. As well as include the bootstrap links

Something like this :

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
```